# The operator * is undefined

Tags: java, android, undefined, operator-keyword

I am trying to make a simple calculator that multiples. I have most of it done, but I keep getting the same error: The operator * is undefined for the argument types Double, EditText.

I searched the questions asked by others, but the only simple one dealt with something different than doubles. Does anyone know how to fix it?

```
package com.deitel.multiplicationtables;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.view.View;

//Implements the listener for an onclick event (implements View.onClickListener)
public abstract class Main extends Activity implements View.OnClickListener{
   // creates a button 
    private Button one, two, three, four, five, six, seven, eight, nine;

    // Called when the activity is first created.
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

      //assigns the resource id of 1 - 9 to each button.
        one = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
        two = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);
        three = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button3);
        four = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button4);
        five = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button5);
        six = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button6);
        seven = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button7);
        eight = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button8);
        nine = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button9);

        //Adds the buttons to the onclicklistener
        one.setOnClickListener(this);
        two.setOnClickListener(this);
        three.setOnClickListener(this);
        four.setOnClickListener(this);
        five.setOnClickListener(this);
        six.setOnClickListener(this);
        seven.setOnClickListener(this);
        eight.setOnClickListener(this);
        nine.setOnClickListener(this);

    }

  //creates a method (or action) for when the button is clicked.
    public void onclick(View view)
    {
        //Makes a variable for the entered number
        Double amount;
        Double product;
        Double variable;

        // constants
        final double one = 1; 
        final double two = 2;
        final double three = 3;


        if (view.getId() == R.id.button1)
        {
          variable = one;
        }
        if (view.getId() == R.id.button2)
        {
            variable = two;
        }
        if (view.getId()== R.id.button3)
        {
            variable = three;
        }




        //creates an editext and assigns the resource id of the xml edittext.
        EditText number = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText1);



        //Receives the input from the edittext, converts it to a double (number).
        amount = Double.parseDouble(number.getText().toString());
        //Calculates the product
        product = variable * number;


        //Creates a textview object, assigns the xml r.id, and then changes the text to report the amount.
         TextView t = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView2); 
            t.setText("Your product is: " + product);

    }



}
```

Comment: It needs to be said:  Having "constants" named `one`, `two` and `three` is even worse than having magic numbers.  It opens the door to such screwed-upness as `final double two = 15;` -- and if that was your intent, then may $DEITY have mercy on your soul.

Answer (score 6):

```
 EditText number = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText1);


 product = variable * number;
```

`number` is of type `EditText`. You can't apply `*` on `EditText` and double.

Your product calculation should be:

```
   product = variable * amount;
```

`amount` is the value you got from `EditText`

Comment: It was confusing to use the variable number to hold a string.

Answer (score 3):

You have converted the text to a value called `amount`, but you have forgotten to use it.

The line

```
product = variable * number;
```

should be

```
product = variable * amount;
```

This should fix the problem.

Answer (score 3):

```
 //creates an editext and assigns the resource id of the xml edittext.
        EditText number = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText1);

        //Calculates the product
        product = variable * number;
```

you are trying to multiply a `double (variable)` with `EditText (number)` type, thus the `Error`

**EDIT for your local variables error:**

`local variables` do not get their `default` values, you have to `initialize` them before you use them inside a method

```
 public void onclick(View view)
    {
        //Makes a variable for the entered number
        Double amount=0.0; //initialize this
        Double product=0.0;//initialize this
        Double variable=0.0;//initialize this
```

Comment: Thank you, I have changed that, but it's still not working. It says "The local variable, variable may not have been initialized."

Comment: You should use `double` instead of `Double` for efficiency.